# What arthropod is this?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

Location: Johannesburg, South Africa

Colour: Brown/Grey

Legs: 6 or 7 pairs

Size: ~10mm

I've been finding these guys in my bath tub the past two mornings. I've caught and released them. I'd like to know what they are so that I can decide whether pest-control measures are needed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is an Isopod crustacean, in the suborder Oniscidea https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse. These are harmless, so I would not worry about contacting pest control. They are also known as "pillbugs".

Comment: It should be mentioned that they are a good indicator of moisture problems as they only like very damp conditions, if you are continuing to see them you may want to start looking for leaks, rot, and mold. they also indicate easy access for other insects so you may want to start sealing cracks. https://pestcontrolcanada.com/sow-bugs-pill-bugs/